# Validation model of Password (Razor Page)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In my pageMode Code

```
l` public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string LoginId { get; set; } = null!;

        [Required]
        public string  Password { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public LoginViewModel Input { get; set; } = null!;`
```

And in view

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group-with-label mb-4">
                    <label>UserId</label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.LoginId" class="form-control-input" autocomplete="off" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.LoginId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group-with-label login-input-password mb-2">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input class="form-control-input" type="password" asp-for="Input.Password" autocomplete="off" />
                    <span class="fa fa-eye" id="togglePassword"></span>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
```

When I submit Login button -> all case ModalState Valid or Invalid when return Page() input type Password always clear value and when I change type of Password from password to text, every thing will OK.

Please help to keep my input password all cases(After post value)

Answer (score 0):

One method is set the type to `text` in password input then change it in JavaScript, the code like

```
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group-with-label mb-4">
        <label>UserId</label>
        <input asp-for="Input.LoginId" class="form-control-input" autocomplete="off" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.LoginId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group-with-label login-input-password mb-2">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input id="passwordInput" class="form-control-input" type="text" asp-for="Input.Password" autocomplete="off" />
        <span class="fa fa-eye" id="togglePassword"></span>
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>



@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var passElem = $("#passwordInput");
            passElem.prop("type", "password");
        });
    </script>
}
```

But I don't recommend this method. In my opinion, You should let the user decide whether to allow the browser to remember their username and password, Just like this:

[image]

===============update================

```
@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. but It may be not my situation. 
Both userId and password are required field. So when I only input Password -> the OnPost method will check ModalState is Invalid and return Page, But in view input value for Password ( after call OnPost) is clear -> And when I click submit again it will display 2 message required for Userid and password.
This behaviour not good for me. So please hint  for me. Thansk

Comment: @ha169169, Check my update in answer, you can add this script in your page, so that when you only input password and submit the form, the form will not be submitted and show error message directly, This is client validation, Only all the input fields fit the validation rule the form can be submitted.